# JSON.NET - getting particular properties inside objects from Jarray

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

There is a series of JSON objects called "issues", which each have one or more "issue links", which have the following format:

```
// an issue link
{
  "id": "000000",
  "self": "some link",
  "type": {
    "id": "0000",
    "name": "some name",
    "inward": "is met by",
    "outward": "meets",
    "self": "some link"
  },
  "outwardIssue": {
    "id": "000000",
    "key": "the required key",
    "self": "some link",
    "fields": {
      // the remainder is not applicable
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These "issue links" have been extracted as follows. Create a JArray for the JSON for the "issue" itself, and extract the child JObjects:

```
public void Deserialize(dynamic jsonObject)
{
    // get the issue links
    if (jsonObject["fields"]["issuelinks"]!=null)
    {
        JArray issueLinksArray = jsonObject["fields"]["issuelinks"];
        var issueLinkObjects = issueLinksArray.Children();
        foreach (var issueLink in issueLinkObjects)
        {
             // now need the "key" in the "outwardIssue" for this object, if the value of "inward" is "is met by".
        }
    }
}
```

How to go about extracting the value of the second property `"key"` of `"outwardIssue"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether I fully understand but following excerpt gets u the value (or null if condition not met) like this.

```
 var key = issueLink["type"]["inward"].ToString()=="is met by" ? issueLink["outwardIssue"]["key"]: null;
```

Hint: Try to avoid dynamic.

Nowadays loops can in certain conditions considered old-school. Think LINQ: The problem can be divided into smaller probs and distributed across multiple lines (think-steps).
The additional variables might improve readability. As the project grows, for loops are prone to span more and more lines. So if you just need requested values following might be of interest:

```
var inwardLinks = issueLinkObject.Where(i=>i["type"]["inward"].ToString()=="is met by");
var keys = inwardLinks.Select(iwl=>iwl["outwardIssue"]["key"]);
```